# How can I patch the abstract, list of figures, and list of tables macros to be included in the ToC automatically?

Tags: table-of-contents, environments, tocloft, etoolbox, patching

We can definitely use `\phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{<name>}` right after we begin the environments or type the relevant macro, which would include abstract, list of figures and list of tables in the ToC. Is here a way to patch these commands so that we no longer need to type `\phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{<name>}`?

This question is meant to teach me how to patch commands with an example, not that I don't want to manually use `\phantomsection` and `\addcontentsline`

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{book}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\frontmatter}{\pagenumbering{roman}}{\pagenumbering{Roman}}{}{}

% ===== Define abstract environment =====
\makeatletter
\if@titlepage
\newenvironment{abstract}{%
    \titlepage
    \null\vfil
    \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
    \begin{center}%
        \bfseries \abstractname
        \@endparpenalty\@M
\end{center}}%
{\par\vfil\null\endtitlepage}
\else
\newenvironment{abstract}{%
    \if@twocolumn
    \section*{\abstractname}%
    \else
    \small
    \begin{center}%
        {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
    \end{center}%
    \quotation
    \fi}
{\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
\fi
\makeatother


\begin{document}




\frontmatter

\pagestyle{plain}

\tableofcontents


\pagestyle{headings}

\cleardoublepage
\begin{abstract}
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \blindtext
\end{abstract}
\phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\abstractname}


\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\listoftables


\mainmatter

\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument


\end{document}
```

Comment: You can add the line into the definition of abstract, see my answer from earlier today. For the list of stuff, simply use package tocbibind

Comment: Yes, but how about the list of tables and list of figures?

Comment: Package `tocbibind`. See section 2.1 of the documentation.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is *nothing* to patch inside `abstract` for the `book` class -- there is no such environment at all for `book`.

If `report` or `article` is used, the `abstract` package by Peter Wilson/Will Robertson can be applied with the `addtotoc` option.

If there is no `abstract` environment, it has to be either defined in a free manner or the code must be copied over from the aforementioned classes as well as `\abstractname`, then say `\usepackage[addtotoc]{abstract}`.

The solution checks whether the class is `report`, `article` or something else and defines the `abstract` environment, then loads the `abstract` package afterwards to give it a chance modifying the environment.

The ToC entries for list of figures and list of tables can be achieved with `tocbibind` as mentioned by [Johannes_B](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/37907/johannes-b).

[image]

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{book}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\frontmatter}{\pagenumbering{roman}}{\pagenumbering{Roman}}{}{}




% ===== Define abstract environment =====
\makeatletter
\@ifclassloaded{report}{%
  % Do nothing, everything seems to be setup already
}{\@ifclassloaded{article}{%
    % Do nothing, everything seems to be setup already
  }{%
    % Any other class that does not provide an abstract environment

    % We have to define `\abstractname` and the abstract environment (most likely)
    % After that, load the abstract package

    \@ifundefined{abstractname}{\newcommand{\abstractname}{Abstract}}{}
    \@ifundefined{abstract}{%

      \if@titlepage
      \newenvironment{abstract}{%
        \titlepage
        \null\vfil
        \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
        \begin{center}%
          \bfseries \abstractname
          \@endparpenalty\@M
        \end{center}}%
      {\par\vfil\null\endtitlepage}
      \else
      \newenvironment{abstract}{%
        \if@twocolumn
        \section*{\abstractname}%
        % \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\abstractname} Or add it here....
        \else
        \small
        \begin{center}%
          {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
        \end{center}%
        \quotation
        \fi}
      {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
      \fi

      % Eventually a check about the existence of \endabstract, i.e. \@ifundefined{endabstract}{}{}

    }{%
      % abstract environment presumably exists
    }
  }% End of \@ifclassloaded{article}
}% End of \@ifclassloaded{report}
\makeatother


\usepackage[addtotoc]{abstract}




\begin{document}




\frontmatter

\pagestyle{plain}

\tableofcontents


\pagestyle{headings}

\cleardoublepage
\begin{abstract}
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \blindtext
\end{abstract}


\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage
\listoftables


\mainmatter

\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument


\end{document}
```